# Change css with jQuery after ajax call

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I´m doing this:

```
jQuery("#foto").click(function() {
 setTimeout(function () { 
  jQuery(".mfp-iframe").delay(0).css({"width":"80%", "height":"89%", "top":"40px"});
 }, 500);
});
```

and it works but when I call more items with ajax (infinite scroll load more items)
this can´t works with the new item with the id #foto I know why, but I need a tip or a method for apply this click function to the new items each time that it needs.

Please help .

Comment: You shouldn't use a same ID for multiple nodes

Comment: a little HTML would help to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: @JonathanNungaray do you load `#foto` link with ajax again?

Comment: Yes but now I have the answer for it thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't use same id for multiple elements in the same document - use a class name instead, for e.g: `.foto`.

The `click` shorthand only binds the event handler to elements present in DOM at the moment.

Since the items are added dynamically, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

try

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.foto',function() {
 setTimeout(function () { 
  jQuery(".mfp-iframe").delay(0).css({"width":"80%", "height":"89%", "top":"40px"});
 }, 500);
});
```

Comment: is the button added dynamically??

Comment: this has an error with the syntax but i dont know which

Comment: @Jai OP mentioned "this can´t works with the new item with the id #foto" new item, so probably it's being added dynamically...

Comment: This is the answer thanks!

jQuery(document).on('click','#foto',function() {
 setTimeout(function () { 
  jQuery(".mfp-iframe").delay(0).css({"width":"80%", "height":"89%", "top":"40px"});
 }, 500);
});

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.on` for newly created elements.

But you cannot use same `id` for more than one elements so change it to some class like below :

assigne `id="foto"` for all elements for which you want to call click function.

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".foto",function() {
     setTimeout(function () { 
      jQuery(".mfp-iframe").delay(0).css({"width":"80%", "height":"89%", "top":"40px"});
     }, 500);
    });
```

Comment: How this is different from OP?? This does not solve the issue.

Comment: Please try updated answer and don't forget to assign class="foto" to all your elements for which click event binding.

Answer (score 0):

**I think need a post ajax rebind:**

wrap in a function and call it on ajax success:

```
var photoClick = function(){jQuery("#foto").click(function() {
 setTimeout(function () { 
  jQuery(".mfp-iframe").delay(0).css({"width":"80%", "height":"89%", "top":"40px"});
 }, 500);
});
};
```

Post Ajax Success:

```
success: function(data) {
    elem.replaceWith(data);
    photoClick();
}
```